# Enable TLS 1.2 on windows 10 64-bit + check if it is enabled or not

Tags: powershell, windows-10, sharepoint-online, tls1.2

I want to run my PS1 files which connect to SharePoint online, the script keeps raising this error:-

```
Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

now based on my readings that one reason for getting this error is that we need to enable TLS 1.2 on the client , as mentioned in this link @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client ..

so i tried the steps mentioned in the link, where i added the register key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp` but i can not find this `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp`  as there is no folder named `WinHttp` under `internet settings`... Can anyone advice?on this , why my windows 10 does not have the second registry path + are there other steps that i need to do to enable TLS 1.2 ?

Thanks

Comment: There's no harm in you creating the subkey `WinHttp` yourself.

Comment: @Theo thanks for the info, i added the folder manually >> restarted the machine >> try the script again >> but i got the same error .. any advice? thanks

Answer (score 3):

To ensure TLS 1.2 is used, add this anywhere before the first request you make.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

##### Vscode snippet

If you are using vscode, here is the code for a snippet, so you can quickly add this in your code whenever needed.

```
    "tls12": {
        "prefix": "tls12",
        "body": "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12"
    },
```

Comment: i am calling a .exe inside .ps1 so how i can apply those? Thanks

Comment: as follow `Show-Message -Message "Step 1a: Create groups and adding users to it" 
    & "$HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.exe" "true" $Username $Password`

Comment: @johnGu I do think adding the `[Net.ServicePointManager]` line I mentionned before your `Show-message` line (aka, the line that have the error) should be enough. Basically, you want that line once anywhere in your script before any http call is made or in your case, that exe is called.

Comment: so what will be the exact syntax ?

Comment: will it be as follow `Show-Message -Message "Step 1a: Create groups and adding users to it" 
    & "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 $HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.exe" "true" $Username $Password
`?